# Address feature missing in Nominatim returned data

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

When you search http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org the details page shows a lot of information and some are missing when querying nominatim.

For example when I search for "choisy" : http:/nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=xml&limit=5&addressdetails=1&q=choisy

(I removed a slash of http:// because I'm not allowed to post 2 links ...)

Result on nominatim : http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=158972963

Result I get with the httprequest is the following:

It's missing (from the "Address" table on the page) in my returned XML result.

> "Haute-Savoie boundary:administrative relation 7407   6   0"

Do you know how to get it ?

Comment: This result contains "Haute-Savoie" in the display_name field: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Choisy%2C+Annecy&polygon=1&format=json&addressdetails=1

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432275/administrative-relations-of-a-place-with-openstreetmap

Comment: It contains a lot of things, are they ordered by administrative_level ?

Comment: Yes, kind of. It's an address hierarchy.

Comment: Perfect I hope it has the same hierarchy depending on countries i'll test it thanks for your help

Comment: It's not that easy since a) every country has a slightly different administrative system (see the [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative)) and b) for some addresses/locations one or several parts of the address hierarchy will be missing in OSM.

Comment: I know for the country already seen that hierarchy, when it's missing, do you know if it'll be ignored or appear as an empty string ? It's weird that it only appear in display_name field and not extracted to a proper field

Comment: It won't appear at all. Nominatim tries to break down addresses into parts but it doesn't seem to have a representation for all of these parts yet (in this specific case for admin_level=6). Thus some things will only appear in the display name.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help maybe this feature will come with Nominatim in futur updates